# How do I add a slider to an AppIndicator?

Tags: indicator, application-development, c

I'm trying to add a slider to an AppIndicator similar to what the Sound Menu has. I've looked trough the code of the Sound Menu and found that I should be using libido-0.1 for that. Here's what I have so far and all I see is a '-' symbol in the menu.

```
indicator_menu = gtk_menu_new();
ido_slider_widget = ido_scale_menu_item_new_with_range("BRIGHTNESS", IDO_RANGE_STYLE_DEFAULT,  0, 0, 100, 1);
ido_scale_menu_item_set_primary_label(IDO_SCALE_MENU_ITEM(ido_slider_widget), "BRIGHTNESS");
ido_scale_menu_item_set_style(IDO_SCALE_MENU_ITEM(ido_slider_widget), IDO_SCALE_MENU_ITEM_STYLE_LABEL);
ido_scale_menu_item_set_primary_label(IDO_SCALE_MENU_ITEM(ido_slider_widget), " - ");
ido_scale_menu_item_set_secondary_label(IDO_SCALE_MENU_ITEM(ido_slider_widget), " + ");

GtkMenuItem *menu_slider_item = GTK_MENU_ITEM(ido_slider_widget);

gtk_menu_append(indicator_menu, GTK_WIDGET(menu_slider_item));
gtk_menu_append(indicator_menu, gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("dfdsfds"));

gtk_widget_show_all(indicator_menu);
gtk_widget_show_all(ido_slider_widget);

app_indicator_set_menu(indicator, GTK_MENU(indicator_menu));
```

Thank you in advance for any posible answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've asked the question on the ayatana mailing list and received an answer from Ted Gould:

> Unfortunately that's not possible today.  It's been our intention to
>   support custom menu items in dbusmenu so that you could do anything that
>   your app needed for your application indicator (including using IDO) but
>   I haven't found the time yet to complete it :-/

So the answer can be closed.

EDIT: In case anyone has further interest in the project they could try contacting Ted  to see how they could help out.

Comment: is it still not possible ?