# Application indicator + entry widget

Tags: indicator, application-development, development

I would like write my own application indicator via guide in
http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/ (in python)

My question - Is there any chance add next to icon indicator entry
widget (see below) on top panel?

```
(
  window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
  vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
  window.add(vbox)
  vbox.show()
  entry = gtk.Entry()
  entry.set_max_length(50)
  entry.set_text("hello")
  vbox.pack_start(entry, True, True, 0)
  entry.show()
  window.show()
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AppIndicators currently do not support this kind of complexity. They might support complex widgets in the future, but for now you can only use simple textual items.

[How do I add a slider to an AppIndicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55290/adding-a-slider-to-appindicator)