# Custom widgets/controls in application indicators

Tags: application-development, python, indicator, quickly, widgets

I want to develop an app for ubuntu, that integrates inside the calendar indicator/menu. It should allow to enter info right from it, and have several controls like input boxes, drop downs, spinners and buttons.

Is this possible to integrate/replace the standard date/time indicator?

If not, is it possible to create it as a separate indicator that when clicked opens a popup with all the controls and stuff?

I want it to look as part of the sys tray and not as a separate desktop app.

I'm using Quickly for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, I want to create something like this:
http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/fantastical/id435003921?mt=12

Comment: Anyone? :( Or any other suggestion on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't integrate with the date/time/calendar indicator AFAIK.

You can't add fancy custom menu items either: https://askubuntu.com/a/57276/67335.

So you're left with writing your own indicator which would have a menu and that menu would then launch your config dialog containing the calendar or whatever you needed.

To get you started: https://askubuntu.com/a/501053/67335.