# Universal appindicator wrapper

Tags: unity, indicator, system-tray

Suffering from ditched system tray support in 13.04. :(
Is it technically possible to create universal appindicator wrapper for arbitrary application which supports only system tray icon? Maybe there are already existing infamous projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal wrapper (not that I've found), but the best thing (that I **did** find) is copy and learn...

1) Some [documentation](https://askubuntu.com/a/491886/67335).

2) Many [indicators](https://askubuntu.com/q/30334/67335) with their source from which to choose and model.

3) My [own](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) indicators are a good starting point ;-)