# Implementation of a slider on appindicator

Tags: application-development, indicator, c

I'm trying to add a slider to an indicator to port my gnome-shell extension to unity. I found out this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55290/how-do-i-add-a-slider-to-an-appindicator) which is exactly my problem. 
If this is not possible using libido and indicator how is the sound indicator implemented ?

Answer (score 2):

The sound indicator is not exported from an application. If you create a media-player, you never specify that there are sliders or play-pause buttons, you just say, that the application is a media-player.

Your problem is, that you can not sent the information "I need a slider" to the software which creates the menus. It is not that this software can not create sliders.

For details of the implementation, you can look at the code: `bzr branch lp:indicator-sound`