# Example of text entry in AppIndicator menu

Tags: indicator

I have written an App Indicator, which currently has a menu.

I would like one of the menu entries to be a short text entry field instead.

Is this possible, and if so, where should I look for an example or documentation?

(The calendar and volume indicators have more complex dropdowns, so it look possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55290/adding-a-slider-to-appindicator) is a little dated, based on a bit of Googling, sadly the situation has not changed.